# Make a better sqlite query from Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, subquery

I'm trying to get an average salary per year from a table. I was looking into subqueries but I'm not sure if that will solve my problem. I have solved this by using a combination of more than one Sqlite query with and for-loop but it's time consuming and I want to have one query for this...But is this possible?

```
Tablename = salaries
Columns = user, year, salary, month
```

Month will go from 01-12. Column year will then have 12 inputs for same year.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT min(year), max(year) FROM salaries WHERE user='DICK';
```

This will give me the start and end year for salary, not what I want.

```
SELECT avg(salary) FROM salaries WHERE user='DICK';
```

This will give me average salary for all working year...almost what I want but I really want per year.

```
        // I took the input from "SELECT min(year), max(year) FROM salaries WHERE user='DICK';" to get min and max for start-year and end-year

        for (int i = startYearInt; i < (endYearInt + 1); i++) {
            String currentYear = "" + i;
            cursor5 = SQLiteDb.rawQuery("SELECT avg(salary) FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE user='"+ USER_ID+"' AND year=" + currentYear, null);
            while (cursor5.moveToNext()) {
                String avgYearSalary = cursor5.getString(0);
                Log.d("log", "avgYearSalary: " + currentYear + ": " + avgYearSalary.toString());
            }
```

So how can I solve this if I don't want to run several queries to the table? It's a really big DB so every query will take about 30sec. I think the DB is about 2,5 million rows:)

How to make a better query so I can stop using the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the average salary that DICK perceived, per year (not a specific year but all years):

```
cursor5 = SQLiteDb.rawQuery("SELECT avg(salary) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE user = '" + USER_ID + "' GROUP BY year", null);
```

Comment: Pure magic:) That is what I wanted....Thanks!
Can I ask you one more faviour?
That will return the list:
salaryX
salaryY
salaryZ

But if I wanted the years as well so it becomes to columns?
YearA, salaryX
YearB, salaryY
yearC, salaryZ

Comment: `"SELECT year, avg(salary) ...` ?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking before I was trying myself:
SELECT avg(salary), year FROM  salaries  WHERE userId = 'EHANMAL' GROUP BY year

This was my latest question.
Now I'm finished...tahnks for all your help

Comment: I'm actually doing this for a about four userIds now. So that will be four SQLite queries. But how can I do this in one query?

Comment: `... WHERE user IN ('Dick', 'Buck', 'Jane', 'Larry') GROUP BY year` or (better) `... WHERE user IN (?, ?, ?, ?) GROUP BY year", new String[]{"Dick", "Buck", "Jane", "Larry"}`

Comment: No that combined the salary for those years they have in common.
I still want the "avg(salary)" per year and per UserId. How can this be done?

Comment: Yes... instead of your current `WHERE`, use this alternative one. The old one uses only Dick as user id. This one uses 4 employees, as you required. And doesn't change the AVG per year extraction.

Comment: SELECT avg(salary), year, userId FROM salaries WHERE userId IN ('DICK', 'JANE','LARRY','BUCK') GROUP BY year
I did it like this but like I said: It's still combined avg(salary) per year. In other word it will be an average salary for all four during one year, through all years. If all four have worked year 2007, I want it to be four average salary for 2007.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I misunderstood. Then it's much simpler: `SELECT avg(salary), year, userId FROM salaries GROUP BY year, userId` This groups by year AND THEN by UserId

Comment: SELECT avg(salary), year, userId FROM salaries WHERE userId IN ('DICK', 'JANE','LARRY','BUCK')  GROUP BY year, userId
This worked:)

Comment: So, you wanted it limited to 4 employees. I misunderstood again... ;)

Comment: For the future, instead of adding questions to a closed question, ut's better to post a new question. So to maintain the 1:1 paradigm